# how to play alarm sound without user interaction andriod

Tags: android

I want to play alarm sound without user interaction in an  android application 
I used this code but when it is not working, no alarm sound is running on, do I have to set a permission ?

```
if (face == null) {
            Uri alarmTone = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_ALARM);
            Ringtone ringtoneAlarm = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(getApplicationContext(), alarmTone);
            ringtoneAlarm.play();


        }
```

Comment: Seems like your project is not synced properly. Try rebuilding the project.

Comment: Try clear cache and restart option